# CSV append, adding values

Tags: python-3.x, csv, append

I have a program that creates a .csv file, and there is one column in the file that is giving me trouble. I have a running count of words for the file (totalWords). Here is my code that is creating the problem column:

```
list.append(("No. of Words", totalWords, "numeric",   "total"))
```

However, rather than listing the individual values when the rows in the column are created, it is adding values.  It should be placing a value for the word count in each line, but it is adding the values together. For example, the first line has two words, and the first row in the column has "2" as its value, so it is correct. The second line in the file has 8 words, and the second row in the column has "10" as its value, so it is adding the two together, and so on. I assume this has something to do with appending, but I am at a loss for how to go about fixing this.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at what a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is. It's a mutable object, meaning it will change values without having to reassign it. Check out this example:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l
>>> [1, 2, 3]
l.append(4)  # no assignment made
l
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
l = [1, 2, 3]  # new assignment
l
>>> [1, 2, 3]
l.pop()  # no assignment made
>>> 3
l
>>> [1, 2]
```